# Created By field returning as 'None'

Tags: python, web2py

In my web2py application, I'm using an SQLFORM to add data into the db table called 'review'.

However, the created_by field is returning as none when it should display the logged in user's first name.

Any idea on what may be wrong and how I could rectify this?

Controller - default.py

```
def addReview():
    response.menu = [
        (T('Back to Reviews'), False, URL('default', 'index'))
    ]
    review_form = SQLFORM(db.review)

    if review_form.process().accepted:
        session.flash = 'Review has been added!'
    elif review_form.errors:
        response.flash = 'Please review the form for errors'

    return dict(review_form=review_form)
```

Model - db.py

```
db.define_table('product',
    Field('name', requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY(), IS_ALPHANUMERIC()]),
    Field('description', 'text', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('stock_level', 'integer')
)

db.define_table('review',
    Field('product', 'reference product', writable=False, readable=False),
    Field('title', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('body', 'text', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('created_by', 'reference auth_user', writable=False),
    Field('added', default=request.now, writable=False)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Field('created_by', 'reference auth_user', writable=False)
```

The `created_by` field is not writable, and no default is specified, so when an insert is made, there is no value for this field. If you want a value inserted, you must specify a default. Probably you want the currently logged in user:

```
    Field('created_by', 'reference auth_user', writable=False, default=auth.user_id)
```